# use of Explicit localization on the grid view of asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, localization

how to provide Explicit Localization on the GridView's Headertext of Asp.net application?

Answer (score 2):

I have not used web forms in a while, so forgive me if this is a little rusty, but as I recall, it is no different than accessing a resource anywhere else in the .aspx page.

BoundField:

```
<asp:BoundField datafield="Date" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Strings, Grid_Header_Date %>" />
```

TemplateField:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Strings, Grid_Header_Date %>">
    <ItemTemplate>
        ...
    <ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```